For incompressible fluids, does the velocity increase or decrease when the fluid enters the divergent nozzle through an equal diameter pipe?
For incompressible fluids, does the velocity increase or decrease when the fluid enters the divergent nozzle through an equal diameter pipe?
People generally believe that speed decreases, but I believe that speed initially increases. So the pressure in the divergent nozzle will decrease at the beginning, not increase.

What does the Bernoulli equation tell you?

@ChetMiller So how is the low pressure generated in the divergent nozzle?

How far upstream do you want to go?

@ChetMiller  What I'm talking about is the divergent nozzle.

The pressure at the throat of a divergent nozzle is lower than the exit pressure.

@ChetMiller Please write an answer explaining the reason.

If there is steady flow and the liquid is incompressible, then by equation of continuity,
A1v1 = A2v2
As area increases, velocity decreases, and from bernoulli, the pressure should increase.
But here's the thing, if the pressure outside was less than the the pressure inside, there is no force to make it the liquid slow down and occupy the entire area. You may have that water when flowing from a tap (flow should be slow, for steady flow) actually becomes thinner as it goes down. It happens because its speed increases and equation of continuity is applicable. This happens because the outside pressure (atmospheric) is not enough to make the water maintain the bigger cross sectional area. So if the fluid enters a divergent nozzle, it may not even occupy the entire area, causing equation of continuity and bernoulli's theorem to fail.
Now if you were talking in a case, where the fluid is strictly in steady flow then the pressure outside must be greater, or it will not expand to occupy the bigger area. Other than that, in this case, bernoulli's theorem is perfectly applicable.

Why is the pressure outside greater than the pressure inside?

In the first sentence, don't you mean "incompressible"?

@D.Halsey yeah, i meant incompressible.

@enbin imagine you have a garden hose and then there is a sudden increase in cross-sectional area. You will find that that water coming out will not spread out to occupy the bigger area. This is because there isn't enough pressure outside to slow down the water, giving it enough time to occupy the bigger area. Also by bernoulli's theorem, as flow is slower outside, then some net negative work must be done on the water. Therefore, the pressure acting against the flow of water must be greater. If the speed outside is not less, then water going in the hose and comming out is not equal.
